Corporate iOS apps distribution via Apple Business Manager and Intune company portal
we have developed an corporate mobile app for iOS. We are using Apple Business Manager and it is connected to Intune company portal.
I have published the app in the app store connect using private distribution mode.
I can see the app in the ABM and I was able to successfully install the app to a managed device via Intune company portal.  When I tried to install the app on an unmanaged device using the web version of company portal I got an error saying that I have to enroll the device to install the app.
Most of the users won't enroll their devices.
Can you please suggest a solution that contains the following:

App available to employees only.
Able to install on managed devices.
Able to install on unmanaged devices. User has to login to company tenant to install the app.

Thanks
